# Why can't I go back to the authentication function after I pressed the logout button

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is what I think I am having a problem with this code, but if this is vague please let me explain furthermore to you.

```
import { database } from "../config/firebase";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

    //User log out
    const history = useNavigate();

    function logOut() {
      signOut(database).then(val => {
        history('/');
      });
    }

          <div className= 'logoutButton'>
            <button onClick={logOut}>Logout</button>
          </div>
```

For Authentication function-----

```
import { auth } from "../config/firebase";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { useState } from "react";
import './auth.css';
import { FaUser } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FiLock } from "react-icons/fi";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


export const Auth = () => {
    
    const [email, setEmail] =  useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] =  useState("");
    const history = useNavigate();

    const Login = async () => {
        try{
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(data => {
                history('/dashboard'); 
            })
        } catch (err){
            console.error(err);
        }
    };

    return( 
<div className= "loginButton-container">
<button onClick={Login} className= "loginButton">Login</button>
</div>
```

I tried this code but after I pressed the logout button it didnt go back to the authentication function

Comment: If you can add your router and how the authentication function works, people can have a better idea on whats going on inorder to help you... 

Comment: What is the authentication function you are trying to get back to? What is the logout button? Please [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] and clearer details for what the issue or problem is. See [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips how to improve the quality of your post to get it more on-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you should [edit] to include your router and routing configuration so we can see what you are rendering per URL path and trying to navigate to, and anything else between *that* and the UI components you are specifically working with. In most cases though I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to navigate to your root `"/"` route. What exactly is the issue? Are there any errors in the console? Can you provide more complete details?